# Invalid cast exception

Tags: c#

I am posting this because the last time I asked this question it did not get solved and I cannot seem to solve this on my own. I am very very new to C# and programming, trying to teach myself so and help you can give would be great.

So on to the error :

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form1+comoditys]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form2+mycost]'.

form2 code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace test
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public float Alligor;
    public float Briochit;
    public float Chollonin;
    public float Espitium;
    public float Hydrobenol;
    public float Isopropenetol;
    public float Metachropin;
    public float Phlobotil;
    public float Plasteosine;
    public float Polynitrocol;
    public float Polynucleit;
    public float Prilumium;
    public float Statchanol;
    public float Titanium;
    public float Vitricyl;

    public float AlligorInput;
    public float BriochitInput;
    public float CholloninInput;
    public float EspitiumInput;
    public float HydrobenolInput;
    public float IsopropenetolInput;
    public float MetachropinInput;
    public float PhlobotilInput;
    public float PlasteosineInput;
    public float PolynitrocolInput;
    public float PolynucleitInput;
    public float PrilumiumInput;
    public float StatchanolInput;
    public float TitaniumInput;
    public float VitricylInput;

    public float costofAlligor;
    public float costofBriochit;
    public float costofChollonin;
    public float costofEspitium;
    public float costofHydrobenol;
    public float costofIsopropenetol;
    public float costofMetachropin;
    public float costofPhlobotil;
    public float costofPlasteosine;
    public float costofPolynitrocol;
    public float costofPolynucleit;
    public float costofPrilumium;
    public float costofStatchanol;
    public float costofTitanium;
    public float costofVitricyl;

    public double totalCost;

    [Serializable]
    public class mycost
    {
        public float secondPrice;
    }

    private List<mycost> costList = new List<mycost>();

    private mycost o1 = null;
    private mycost o2 = null;
    private mycost o3 = null;
    private mycost o4 = null;
    private mycost o5 = null;
    private mycost o6 = null;
    private mycost o7 = null;
    private mycost o8 = null;
    private mycost o9 = null;
    private mycost o10 = null;
    private mycost o11 = null;
    private mycost o12 = null;
    private mycost o13 = null;
    private mycost o14 = null;
    private mycost o15 = null;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        o1 = new mycost();
        o2 = new mycost();
        o3 = new mycost();
        o4 = new mycost();
        o5 = new mycost();
        o6 = new mycost();
        o7 = new mycost();
        o8 = new mycost();
        o9 = new mycost();
        o10 = new mycost();
        o11 = new mycost();
        o12 = new mycost();
        o13 = new mycost();
        o14 = new mycost();
        o15 = new mycost();

        costList.Add(o1);
        costList.Add(o2);
        costList.Add(o3);
        costList.Add(o4);
        costList.Add(o5);
        costList.Add(o6);
        costList.Add(o7);
        costList.Add(o8);
        costList.Add(o9);
        costList.Add(o11);
        costList.Add(o12);
        costList.Add(o13);
        costList.Add(o14);
        costList.Add(o15);

        FileStream df = new FileStream("comoditys.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter abf = new BinaryFormatter();
        costList = (List<mycost>)abf.Deserialize(df);
        df.Close();

        if (costList != null)
        {
            if (costList.Count > 0)
                Alligor = costList[0].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 1)
                Briochit = costList[1].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 2)
                Chollonin = costList[2].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 3)
                Espitium = costList[3].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 4)
                Hydrobenol = costList[4].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 5)
                Isopropenetol = costList[5].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 6)
                Metachropin = costList[6].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 7)
                Phlobotil = costList[7].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 8)
                Plasteosine = costList[8].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 9)
                Polynitrocol = costList[9].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 10)
                Polynucleit = costList[10].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 11)
                Prilumium = costList[11].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 12)
                Statchanol = costList[12].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 13)
                Titanium = costList[13].secondPrice;

            if (costList.Count > 14)
                Vitricyl = costList[14].secondPrice;

        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            AlligorInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            BriochitInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            CholloninInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            EspitiumInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            HydrobenolInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

           IsopropenetolInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            MetachropinInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            PhlobotilInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            PlasteosineInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            PolynitrocolInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

           PolynucleitInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            PrilumiumInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

            StatchanolInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

           TitaniumInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void textBox15_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;



        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {

           VitricylInput = tempFloat;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        costofAlligor = Alligor * AlligorInput;
        costofBriochit = Briochit * BriochitInput;
        costofChollonin = Chollonin * CholloninInput;
        costofEspitium = Espitium * EspitiumInput;
        costofHydrobenol = Hydrobenol * HydrobenolInput;
        costofIsopropenetol = Isopropenetol * IsopropenetolInput;
        costofMetachropin = Metachropin * MetachropinInput;
        costofPhlobotil = Phlobotil * PhlobotilInput;
        costofPlasteosine = Plasteosine * PlasteosineInput;
        costofPolynitrocol = Polynitrocol * PolynitrocolInput;
        costofPolynucleit = Polynucleit * PolynucleitInput;
        costofPrilumium = Prilumium * PrilumiumInput;
        costofStatchanol = Statchanol * StatchanolInput;
        costofTitanium = Titanium * TitaniumInput;
        costofVitricyl = Vitricyl * VitricylInput;

        totalCost = costofAlligor + costofBriochit + costofChollonin + costofEspitium + costofHydrobenol + costofIsopropenetol + costofMetachropin + costofPhlobotil + costofPlasteosine + costofPolynitrocol + costofPolynucleit + costofPrilumium + costofStatchanol + costofTitanium + costofVitricyl;

    }

    private void textBox16_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         textBox13.Text = totalCost.ToString();

        }
    }
  }
```

[form1 can be found here](http://pastebin.com/cRy4FJhX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    FileStream df = new FileStream("comoditys.dat", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter abf = new BinaryFormatter();
    costList = (List<mycost>)abf.Deserialize(df);
```

it looks like you are opening the `comoditiys.dat` and it deserializes to `List<comoditys>` but you are casting them incorrectly to `List<mycost>`.

EDIT:

Try this

```
List<comodity> comodities = (List<comodity>)abf.Deserialize(df);
costList = comodities.Select(c => new mycost{secondPrice = c.comodityCost}).ToList();
```

Comment: yes but i need the contents of comoditys.dat to go to the List<mycost> is there a way i can do this ?

Comment: 1 question i get comoditys could not be found do i need to declare the comoditys class in form 2 as well?

Comment: @doc i think the name of the class is just `comodity`.

Comment: yes sorry i declaired it and that fixed 2 errors 1 remains that im a bit puzzled over Error 1 'test.Form2.comoditys' does not contain a definition for 'comodityCost' and no extension method 'comodityCost' accepting a first argument of type 'test.Form2.comoditys' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) for :  secondPrice = c.comodityCost ..??

Comment: do the costlist varibles change from costList.Add to comodityCost.add?

Comment: okay fixed that error but i STILL get the invalad cast exception code changed to this : FileStream df = new FileStream("comoditys.dat", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter abf = new BinaryFormatter();
            List<comoditys> comodities = (List<comoditys>)abf.Deserialize(df);
            costList = comodities.Select(c => new mycost { secondPrice = c.comodityCost }).ToList();
            df.Close();

Comment: @doc what exactly is the message you get with the `InvalidCastException`  this time.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form1+comoditys]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form2+comoditys]'.

Comment: @doc now it's confused between `comoditys` class in form1 and form2. Just delete one of them and use the other.

Comment: so if i change comoditys in form2 to something else it will work .. here is to hoping

Comment: crossed fingers but alas no luck : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form1+comoditys]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form2+goodStuff]'.

Comment: FileStream df = new FileStream("comoditys.dat", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter abf = new BinaryFormatter();
            List<goodStuff> comodityData = (List<goodStuff>)abf.Deserialize(df);
            costList = comodityData.Select(c => new mycost { secondPrice = c.comodityCost }).ToList();
            df.Close(); ... this is the exact code i used

Comment: I'm getting confused too. Try full namespace `List<test.Form1.comoditys> comodityData = (List<test.Form1.comoditys>)abf.Deserialize(df);`

Comment: this was suggested on MSDN : List<T> is already serializable by default; you don't need to create separate container classes for your floats.  Instead of using List<myCost> (in Form2) and List<comodity> in Form1, just use List<float> in both.  If you want to be able to set list elements to null, use the nullable type: List<float?>.  The problem is that, even though myCost and comodity are effectively the same (a wrapper for float), because they have different names and declarations, they are not the same type. .. any merit to this?

Comment: I think the serialization was done with `test.Form1+comoditys` type to `comodities.dat` so if you want to be able to read data back from that file, you don't have much of an option with `BinarySerializer`. But for future use, you can just serialize it as `List<float?>` if all `comodity` is a wrapper for a float/nullable float.

Comment: yes all comodity does is declare a variable as a float to be added to a list

Comment: i tried to change the 2 lists to read : public List<float> comodityCost = new List<float>(); but holy cow the errors that stated popping up

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it comoditys.dat contains a serialised `List<comoditys>` and you are trying to cast the deserialised result to a `List<mycost>`

EDIT

Linq example as per comment, i don't know how a `comoditys` object maps to a `mycost` object so property names are just examples.

```
MyComoditysList.Select(x => new mycost()
{
    myCostProp1 = comoditysProp1,
    myCostProp2 = comoditysProp2,
    myCostProp3 = comoditysProp3
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Erm well you can't, hence the cast exception.  You need to deserialise it to List<comoditys> then you could use Linq to transform it to a List<mycost>

Comment: is there a way to do it that wont give the exception ? any hints or info would be great

Comment: could you give a example of the Linq i have heard it before but have not used it

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess here:

What does `abf.Deserialize(df)` return?

Does it return `List<mycost>` or something else?

Comment: yes it should return a list because that is what is saved to the file it reads

Comment: List<mycost> or someother list<?>

Comment: What does it return?  Debug to that point and find out... I'm guessing its not returning list<mycost>

Comment: This is not an answer, but questions. You should keep those little questions in the comments. Avoid being downvoted: delete the "answer" or rework it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to cast a list of `comoditys` to a list of `mycost`.  You can't do that.  It's difficult to provide any other assistance given the size of your code.  You should try to minimize it to the smallest reproduction of the error you're experiencing.

Comment: i think that is what is going on ... the list comoditys saves to a file the list mycost reads from that same file but i dont know how to fix it if a list cannot be read by another ?